# PHP If Statement for MySQL Query

Tags: php, if-statement

For the life of me I cannot figure this one out, still new so I am probably overlooking.

Based on a POST value, I would like to perform 1 of 3 MySQL queries. I have verified that each query works on its own, when I add the if statement nothing updates. Also not receiving any MySQL errors.

If the POST value is "on" or "off" run the corresponding query to update all columns. 
If the POST value is anything else (would be a column number), toggle that column.

```
<!-- language: lang-php -->
mysql_select_db("lightup") or die(mysql_error());

if ($light=="on")
    {
        $query = mysql_query("UPDATE Homes SET     L1Status='0',L2Status='0',L3Status='0',L4Status='0',L5Status='0',L6Status='0',L7Status='0',L8Status='0',L9Status='0',L10Status='0' WHERE HomeID=$id") or die(mysql_error());
    }

elseif ($light=="off")
    {
    $query = mysql_query("UPDATE Homes SET L1Status='0',L2Status='0',L3Status='0',L4Status='0',L5Status='0',L6Status='0',L7Status='0',L8Status='0',L9Status='0',L10Status='0' WHERE HomeID=$id") or die(mysql_error());
    }

else()
    {
    $query = mysql_query("UPDATE Homes SET $lightcolumn = !$lightcolumn WHERE HomeID=$id") or die(mysql_error());   
    }

mysql_close($link);
```

Any thoughts?

Comment: I know you don't need it, but is it an error to include () after the last else?  I assume $light is correctly getting set using $_POST correct?

Comment: I hope $lightcolumn and $id aren't coming directly from _GET/_POST...

Comment: Marc B, they are. Is that a no no? Suggestion?

Comment: Marc B is right that you should be really aware that anything that comes from $_POST, $_GET, $_COOKIE and some from $_SERVER cannot be trusted. You should *always* filter anything that comes from anywhere you don't control. A quick example (and the least of your problems) would be if someone sends $id as: "0 OR HomeID>0". You can see that that would not give the desired result. This is called SQL INJECTION and there's plenty of material on the subject.

Comment: Thanks Ramon for the explanation, I can definitely see the issue. I will update my queries.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have an error in your syntax in your last `else`, remove the parens, so instead of this:

```
else()
```

it should be this

```
else
```

Comment: Ugh...wow... I have a love hate relationship with this website. I feel like an idiot but learn so much :-) Works perfectly.

Comment: Don't bother, we all have made an overlooked that took us time to find.. but here you'll find plenty of eyes to catch it :-)